# How can I error handle chained http requests individually when using mergeMap in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, angular-httpclient

I am chaining http requests in Angular using `mergeMap`. The chained request works just fine - what I'm having trouble with is the error handling. I would like to run different logic depending on which request fails. For example, if the first request fails I would like to `console.log("failed on request1")`. If the second request fails, I would like to `console.log("failed on request2")`. The (simplified) code for that method looks something like this:

```
  submitRequests(): void {
    this.service.request1()
        .pipe(mergeMap(result => {
          let resultId = result.id;
          return this.service.request2(resultId);
        }))
        .subscribe(() => { console.log("Both requests successful") },
                   err => {
                     // If failed on request1, console.log("failed on request1")
                    // If failed on request2, console.log("failed on request2")
                   });
  }
```

Does anyone know how this is best achieved in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do smth like this:

```
this.service.request1()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(result => {
      let resultId = result.id;
      return this.service.request2(resultId).pipe(catchError(err => {
        // 1. You can handle the error and do some logic here
        // 2. Or you can pass some data in throwError and determine in subscribe (error callback) failed request 

        return throwError(resultId);
      }));
    }),
  ).subscribe(
    () => {},
    failedResultId => console.log(`Failure occured for: ${failedResultId}`)
  );
```

I hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle the errors within one subscribe as you did. We have the error callback, where we get the **HttpErrorResponse**. In this there is **url** property from which you can distinguish which API failed. Example:

```
this.postService.getPosts()
  .mergeMap(posts => {
    console.log("Posts: ", posts);
    return this.postService.getPost(posts[0].userId);
  }).subscribe(posts => {
    console.log("First Post: ", posts);
    this.postsDetails = posts;
    this.loading = false;
  },(error: HttpErrorResponse)=>{
    if(error){
      if(error.url=="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"){
        console.log("Error coming from 1st API");
      }else{
        console.log("Error coming from 2nd API");
      }
    }
  });
```

Here if the `error.url` if it matchs with API url of 1st request, then we can confirm that error is coming from that. Else its coming from second API call.

Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-operators-examples?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstackoverflow%2Fmerge-map-error%2Fmerge-map-error.component.ts

https://angular-rxjs-operators-examples.stackblitz.io/stackoverflow

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this was the best solution I came up with but I thought there might be a better way. The URL of the request includes some dynamic ID, so I was ending up just basically looking to see if there was a substring match. It felt a little janky

Comment: Since we have only single subscription, I don't know if there is any other way, we can distinguish from both. Thank you for your response.